# Xamarin Forms Alert Multiple buttons

Tags: xamarin.forms, alert

I am new to Xamarin forms. I know you can show the alert by using the DisplayAlert but that only has provision for two buttons.

Is there any way I can have an alert with 3 buttons?

Answer (score 11):

What about [`DisplayActionSheet`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Page.DisplayActionSheet/p/System.String/System.String/System.String/System.String%5B%5D/)?

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/pop-ups/

Comment: I had that has an option but was trying to see if anybody had solved the case of using alert.

Comment: I'd like to show message along alert. Actionsheet does not have this option.